# Implementing wildcard search on elements in MarkLogic without enabling it in database

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a scenario where I need to perform a wildcard search on elements but **without enabling wildcard search options for the database**.

I have tried giving indexes to element but yet not able to do wildcard search. Is there any another way to achieve the above mentioned scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you don't want to enable wildcard search on the whole database, just on certain elements? If so, then you want to create a [field](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields#chapter), include whatever your target elements are, and set up wildcard searches on the field.